# rs.next returns only one result in java

Tags: java, sql, database

I am attempting to run following code :

```
ResultSet rs=DatabaseConnection.executeQuery("Select * from csr where c_No="+this.c_No);
if(rs.next()){  
ob_id=rs.getInt("ID");
}

ResultSet rs1=DatabaseConnection.executeQuery("Select * from cs_details");
if(rs1.next()){
cs_id=rs1.getInt("cs_Id");
DatabaseConnection.executeUpdate("Insert into transact (ob_ID, cs_ID, quant) values("+this.ob_id+", "+this.cs_id+", 0)");
}
```

In this code, ob_id returns only one value from database which is true. But second query returns multiple rows from which I need to keep only a single column value i.e. cs_id (every time). But while executing this code, it takes only first cs_id value in database & insert only one record in "transact" table. I need to insert all records with respective values of cs_id. How to solve this problem???

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
if (rs1.next()) {
  cs_id=rs1.getInt("cs_Id");
  DatabaseConnection.executeUpdate("Insert into transact (ob_ID, cs_ID, quant) values("+this.ob_id+", "+this.cs_id+", 0)");
}
```

do

```
while (rs1.next()) {
  cs_id=rs1.getInt("cs_Id");
  DatabaseConnection.executeUpdate("Insert into transact (ob_ID, cs_ID, quant) values("+this.ob_id+", "+this.cs_id+", 0)");
}
```

to loop through all records in the `ResultSet`.

Comment: while loop also returns only one record

Comment: @user3576078 then there is only 1 record returned.

Comment: But result of query "Select * from cs_details" returns 5 records exists in database